# Passing PHP JSON to Javascript: echo json_encode vs echo json declaration

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a common constants file to share between php and javascript, using JSON to store the constants. But I'm wondering why pass the JSON from PHP to javascript using `json_encode()` over echoing the json declaration.

Let's say I have the PHP JSON

```
<?php 

$json_obj = '{"const1": "val",
            "const2": "val2"             
                            }';

?>
```

Googling, it seems the typical way of passing back to javascript is using

```
<?php echo json_encode($json_obj); ?>
```

Then I believe I would have to use something like `$.getScript()` to read the php file to get `$json_obj` and then use `parseJSON()` to make it useable in javascript.

But why not instead

```
<?php  echo 'var json = '.$json_obj; ?>
```

This way all you have to do is load the script directly and you have the json ready to use directly.

Is there a particular reason why it is more favorable to use `json_encode()` then simply echoing the declaration to javascript?

Comment: You use `json_encode` on arrays and objects, what you have there is just a string, not need to encode it.

Comment: What if the variable you want to store your data on client side changes its name? What if you want to use the same data on multiple occasions? What if something already is stored in the global variable `json`? ...

Comment: if you have an array or even an object, like stdClass object, it is easier to use json_encode then to loop through the array/object to print out the contents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case `$json_obj` is already a string. So it is not necessary. But if you have an array you want to pass to javascript `json_encode` will help you with this.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on what you want to send from server to the client - be it a data (JSON) or some code.

Two approaches:

1. Echo a JSON file on a server - then you print your JSON document and set response `Content-Type`  to `application/json`. This way you can use any AJAX library you wish, like `$.get` or raw `XMLHttpRequest` etc. It is a way of passing data.
2. Echo a Javascript code on a server and then use `$.getScript` to load it. It's a way of passing code. This is potentially less secure, because your code can contain not only JSON, but also any arbitary code. So if attacker can compromise your server, he could be able to push code to any client for a remote execution.

If you want to pass data only, go with first approach. It's cleaner and more safe.

Additionally, if you ever end up writing frontend in different environment, say different programming language, you'll be able to resuse the same JSON-returning endpoint. It'll be harder if you return Javascript code.

Answer (score 5):

**Passing PHP JSON to Javascript and reading**

```js
var data = <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>;
var arr = new Array();
arr = JSON.parse(data);
document.write( arr[0].something );
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though it may seem like overkill for your particular problem, I would go for the json_encode/parse option still. Why? you ask. Well, think of it as avoiding duplication. If you encode/parse you can keep the constants in an object easily readable by you PHP-code. And the same for your JS code.

It simply eliminates the need to fiddle with it.

Answer (score 1):

constant.php

```
<?php
$array = array("const1" => "val", "const2" => "val2");
?>
<script>
var contants = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
</script>
```

======================END OF FILE constant.php=======

In php you can access using

```
$array["<key>"]
```

In javascript, you can access using

```
contants.const1, ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is what I do, the safest way I've found:

```
// holds variables from PHP
var stuff = {};
try {
    // stuff will always be an object
    stuff = JSON.parse('<?php echo empty($stuff) ? '{}' : json_encode($stuff) ?>');
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof SyntaxError)
    {
        // report syntax error
        console.error("Cannot parse JSON", e);
    }
}
// show resulting object in console
console.log("stuff:", stuff);
```

Comment: You don't need the `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 0):

You use `json_encode` if you use php array not a string:

```
$array = array("const1" => "val", "const2" => "val2");

echo json_encode($array);
```

if you call json_encode on a string you will get:

```
"{\"const1\": \"val\", \"const2\": \"val2\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `json_encode()` should be a PHP data structure, not a string that's already in JSON format. You use this when you want to pass a PHP object to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

`json_encode` is a function that converts a PHP array into a JSON string, and nothing more. Since your `$json_obj` variable is **already** a JSON string, no further conversion is needed and you can simply echo it out.

To get to your `$json_obj` string from an array your code would have looked like this

```
$json_array = array(
    "const1" => "val",
    "const2" => "val2"
);

$json_obj = json_encode($json_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP To JSON

```
var locations = <?php echo json_encode($sample_location_master); ?>;
```