# How to supply the string created as a results of PHP to my javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a word check script in the input field that i have specified on the variable **selector**. The list of the words are pulled from the database. I have provided the query for the database. The results from the database are

```
>Array
>(
>[0] => Skype
>[1] => Phone
>[2] => Whatsapp
>[3] => Mobile
>[4] => Gmail
>[5] => email
>[6] => viber
>)
```

I am creating the string for the if statement inside my javascript using these above words. The result of $a is

```
 $(selectors)[0].value.search(/Skype/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
   [0].value.search(/Phone/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
   [0].value.search(/Whatsapp/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
   [0].value.search(/Mobile/i) !== -1 || $(selectors)>> 
   [0].value.search(/Gmail/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
   [0].value.search(/email/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
   [0].value.search(/viber/i) !== -1
```

After that i tried to pass this string as a conditions in the script and it will execute the alert every time. I want it to execute only when the words match.

I have already tried writing

```
$(selectors)[0].value.search(/Skype/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
[0].value.search(/Phone/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
[0].value.search(/Whatsapp/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
[0].value.search(/Mobile/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
[0].value.search(/Gmail/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
[0].value.search(/email/i) !== -1 || $(selectors) 
[0].value.search(/viber/i) !== -1
```

inside the if statement and it works perfectly fine, But the reason I want to do this is I don,t want to come back to the code and add another line inside the if statement every time i want to add the word

```
<?php
//testing
$words = array();
$a='';
foreach($db->getRecordSet('SELECT * FROM conversationKeywords WHERE     conStatus = :conStatus',array(':conStatus'=>1)) as $results){
    array_push($words,$results['conKeyWord']);
}
/* //DEVELOPER DEBUGGIN PURPOSES ONLY, UNCOMMENT ON DEVELOPER MACHINE
echo '<pre>';
print_r($words);
echo '</pre>';
*/
foreach($words as $values){
    if(!next($words)) {
        $a.= '$(selectors)[0].value.search(/'.$values.'/i) !== -1';
    }
    else{
        $a.= '$(selectors)[0].value.search(/'.$values.'/i) !== -1 || ';
    }
}
//echo $a;
?>

<script>
    var selectors = "#msg_text,#Message_Text,#job-desc";
    var conditions = <?php echo json_encode($a) ?>;
    console.log(conditions);
    $("body").on("keyup",selectors,function(conditions){

        if(warning !== true){

            //var v = $('#msg_text').val();

            if (conditions){

                //alert("Warning! For safety and quality     assurance, Please note that we kindly request all parties to communicate only     through us.");

        alertify
        .alert("Warning!","For safety and quality assurance,we     kindly request that all parties communicate ONLY through us.", function(){
        alertify.message('OK');});
            //warning = true;
        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: I think [JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528692/passing-php-json-to-javascript-echo-json-encode-vs-echo-json-declaration) is probably part of your solution. Use PHP to output the JSON to your page. Then implement the needed javascript code referencing what was passed in by PHP.

Comment: If you want to pass data to javascript use json_encode. 

But your logic is some way around. It will be easier to do search logic in back-end side. Just create method which accepts word and returns if was found or no. Then you can use this method with AJAX when users submits form or does changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing `$(selectors)[0].value.search(/SEARCHTERM/i) !== -1` over and over again for each search term I recommend to use regex alteration:

```
$(selectors)[0].value.search(/(SEARCHTERM_1|SEARCHTERM_2|SEARCHTERM_3)/i) !== -1
```

You can use PHP [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to create the string of the search terms from your $words variable. Also you should use `$(this).val()` instead of `$(selectors)[0].value` if you want to get the value of the currently focused input element.

Your complete code should be like:

```
<?php
//testing
$words = array();
foreach($db->getRecordSet('SELECT * FROM conversationKeywords WHERE  conStatus = :conStatus',array(':conStatus'=>1)) as $results){
    $words[] = $results['conKeyWord'];
}
?>

<script>
    var selectors = "#msg_text, #Message_Text, #job-desc";
    $("body").on("keyup", selectors, function(){
        if ($(this).val().search(/(<?= implode("|", $words) ?>)/i) !== -1) {
            alertify.alert("Warning!","For safety and quality assurance,we     kindly request that all parties communicate ONLY through us.", function(){
                alertify.message('OK');
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Note: `$words[] = $results['conKeyWord'];` is same as `array_push($words,$results['conKeyWord']);`, but it's faster and cleaner.